# htaccess apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had a  script that  ran  weather  update  urls   in  /weather  which  is now  deleted

These types of urls  are  404'ed    and need to  be redirected  to   /index.php as  I show below

www.atlanticcity.com/weather/index.php?config=&forecast=pass&pass=local_radar&dpp=1&radar_icao=karx&hwvradartype=comp&place=wisconsin+rapids&state=wi&zipcode=&country=us&county=55141&zone=WIZ035

This I tried  and doesnt work....

```
RewriteRule ^weather/(.*)  http://www.atlanticcity.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Hi  Phil-  thanks for pointing that out.  Looked there yesterday  and tried stuff.

Comment: Do you have other rules? is `/weather` a directory?

Comment: I have  a huge  htaccess  file  since the site  was  redone recently.  /weather    does not exist  anymore,  but it was a directly

Comment: Make sure to place that redirect rule as very first rule in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You could use a redirect rule instead of rewrite.  This would have to go in the apache .conf file under the virtual hosts tag.

```
Redirect 302 /weather/.* http://www.atlanticcity.com/index.php
```